# Как ограничить кол-во товара в одни руки Bitrix?

Tags: битрикс

Как ограничить кол-во товара, которое пользователь может добавить в коризну по наличию определенного свойства?

Answer (score 0):

Напишите обработчики для событий корзины - https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/sale/events/events_basket.php

В обработчике проверяйте кол-во в корзине со значением поля в свойстве.

Comment: Пробовал. Метод устарел, а в новом ядре аналога нет.

Comment: @Ex1st в настройках модуля "Интернет-магазин" отмечена опция "Включить обработку устаревших событий"?
В новом ядре обновление корзины есть - https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_d7/bitrix/sale/events/basket_updated.php